# NumberFormatException (Java)

Tags: java, exception, int, try-catch, numberformatexception

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting a "NumberFormatException" error?
My program asks me to input 10 integers, which then get written to a file, and are able to be read back and averaged together.

I can input and write to the file just fine, but I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Inputted integer: 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at average.Average.readRecords(Average.java:99)
    at average.Average.main(Average.java:29)

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
             System.out.printf("Please enter integer %d: ", i+1);
             numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

             {
                 try
                 {
                    output.format("Inputted integer: %s%n", String.valueOf(numbers[i])); 
                 }
                 catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedexception)
                 {
                     System.err.println("Error writing to the file. Terminating.");
                     break;
                 }
                 catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException)
                 {
                     System.err.println("Please restart the program and enter integers ONLY.");
                     break;
                 }
                 catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException)
                 {
                     System.out.print("Check for numbers.txt and see what ya got!");
                 }
```

Full code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;




public class Average {

    private static Formatter output;

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int[] numbers = new int[10];

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            openFile();
            addRecords();
            closeFile();
            readRecords();
        //   closeFile();
        }
        public static void openFile()
        {
            try
            {
                output = new Formatter("numbers.txt");
            }
            catch (SecurityException securityException)
            {
                System.err.println("Write permission denied. Terminating.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
            {
                System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        public static void addRecords()
        {  
            System.out.print("Hello, welcome to my program!\n");

            for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                 System.out.printf("Please enter integer %d: ", i+1);
                 numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

                 {
                     try
                     {
                        output.format("Inputted integer: %s%n", String.valueOf(numbers[i]));
                     }
                     catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedexception)
                     {
                         System.err.println("Error writing to the file. Terminating.");
                         break;
                     }
                     catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException)
                     {
                         System.err.println("Please restart the program and enter integers ONLY.");
                         break;
                     }
                     catch (NoSuchElementException elementException)
                     {
                         System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                         input.nextLine();
                     }
                     catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException)
                     {
                         System.out.print("Check for numbers.txt and see what ya got!");
                     }
                     //System.out.print("? ");
                 }
             }
        }
        public static void closeFile(){
            {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
            }
       }
       public static void readRecords()
       {   
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("numbers.txt"))){
                String line;
                int[] number = new int[10];
                int i=-1;
                while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
                    i++;
                    number [i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
                    System.out.println("number" +i+" = " +number[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (NoSuchFileException noSuchFileException)
            {
                System.out.print("This file was not created properly and cannot be found.");
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException illegalStateException)
            {
                System.out.print("Error reading from file. Terminating");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `%d`?

Comment: Please show an actual console transcript with your input and output and the entire stack trace.  I suspect the error is on the input line AFTER entering `1`.

Comment: Nothing in what you posted here looks like it could throw a `NumberFormatException`.  Print a stack trace and double check where it's coming from.  My bet is on `readRecords()`, where you're trying to parse lines from `numbers.txt`, but this is all guesswork until you flesh out your question.

Comment: @JimGarrison http://imgur.com/xd9y0AN

Comment: @azurefrog http://imgur.com/xd9y0AN

Comment: Now copy that text, and [edit] your question to paste it in there..

Comment: @MadProgrammer because this happens http://imgur.com/MCoDNFg :(

Comment: @Walby `output.format("Inputted integer: %d%n", numbers[i]);` ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer getting the exact same error even after swapping that line

Comment: @Walby `output.format("Inputted integer: %d%n", numbers[i]);` works just fine, the problem, as I've stated, is in your `readRecords` method

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is actually in your `readRecords` method, where you're reading `Inputted integer: 1` and then trying to parse the value to an `int`, which it obviously isn't

You need to extract the number from your text, maybe using something like...

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    i++;
    String[] split = line.split(":");
    line = split[1].trim();
    number[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
    System.out.println("number" + i + " = " + number[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a string for the input, maybe you have to try using
`mystring.trim()` for the blank space before attempting to parse it.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  I know, you don't have the rep. Don't abuse the system by posting comments as answers. Doing so will make it harder to get to the rep needed to post comments.